# Unable to get data from web server in my ios app using NSURLConnection, but I can get it working from the localhost server

Tags: ios, json

I am developing an iphone app which gets JSON data from webserver and I am using NSURLConnectionDelegate,NSURLConnectionDataDelegate,NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate protocols.
I am able to get the data succesfully using the localhost but cannot get it from internet web server.

```
NSURL*url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                      timeoutInterval:60.0];

NSLog(@"%@",theRequest);
// Create the connection with the request and start loading the data.

// NSURLDownload *theDownload = [[NSURLDownload alloc] initWithRequest:Request delegate:self];
NSURLConnection* connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

And the other delegate methods are below

```
  -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{

mydata =[[NSMutableData alloc] init];
[mydata setLength:0];
 }

  -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

 UIAlertView*errorView =[[UIAlertView alloc]  initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"The     download could not be completed- please make sure you are connected to Internet either 3G or Wi-fi" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];


[errorView show];

  }
  -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection{

NSArray*jsonArr =[[NSArray alloc] init];



NSError*error;
jsonArr= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:mydata options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",error);
NSLog(@"Json Array  %@",jsonArr);
self.questions = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:jsonArr];

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
```

}

I am getting this error :
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 3.) UserInfo=0x71be760 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 3.}

which only comes when trying the data from internet webserver and does not occur on accessing localhost

```
  All the code works perfectly if I use url as http://localhost/example.php but as soon  as             

  I change the url to use the web server url  http://www.example.net/data.php 
  although there is no problem with connection but it returns data as nil.
```

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: I believe this error is telling you that the JSON is invalid. The problem is with what the server is sending you, so the problem needs to be fixed there.

Comment: I have checked with - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection
{
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:mydata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Received json:\n%@", jsonString);
}  it logs valid Json when cache timeoutInterval is increased to 120 sec , however the error persists

Comment: I think the Json sent by server has errors , I don't know how to fix the problem.

Comment: Do you have control over what's being sent?